# ZF2: How to get Zend\Navigation inside custom route?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-navigation, zend-router

I have custom router and I have to get access to `Zend\Navigation` inside this custom router. I was googling, asking and searching and no results :/

All I need is to find nodes with 'link' param using Zend\Navigation in my Alias::match function.

Here is my module.config.php:

```
'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            'account' => array(
                'label' => 'Account',
                'route' => 'node',
                'pages' => array(
                    'home' => array(
                        'label' => 'Dashboard',
                        'route' => 'node',
                        'params' => array(
                                    'id' => '1',
                                    'link' => '/about/gallery'
                                    ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
[...]
```

And here is my Alias class:

```
// file within ModuleName/src/ModuleName/Router/Alias.php
namespace Application\Router;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Alias extends Http\Segment implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
    {
        [...]

        return parent::match($request, $pathOffset);        
    }

}
```

**EDITED:**

<strike>Now i know that I should inject service manager into my custom router. Let me know if You know how to do this :)</strike>

**EDITED:**

<strike>Ok, its not custom router but route. My bad. I was talking on `#zftalk` irc chanell and `AliasSegment` class should implements `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`. Ok I've tried it but now there is another problem.</strike>

In `setServiceLocator` function i can't get `service locator`. It returns null object, however `$serviceLocator` is class `Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager`.

```
public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator){
    $sl = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    var_dump($sl); // NULL
}
```

Any ideas how to get Zend navigation from it ?

**EDITED**

Corresponding to what @mmmshuddup said, I've changed my custom router class. (New version is above). Also in my `Module.php`, within `onBootstrap` function, I added this line:

```
$sm->setFactory('Navigation', 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory', true);
```

Navigation works and its instantiated before `route` so it should be visible within my Alias class but it's not.

I've put into my `match` function in `Alias` class this line:

```
$servicesArray = $this->getServiceLocator()->getRegisteredServices();
```

and `$servicesArray` is almost empty. There is no service, no factories. The same line inserted into `onBootstrap`, just after setting new factory (as above) returns array with `navigation` and other services.

The question is: how can i share this array (or ServiceManager) with my custom router: `Alias` ?

I have to say that all I want to do was possible in ZF1 and it was quite easy.

**EDIT**

I found a solution. The answer is below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution but this is **NOT elegant solution** i think. However everything works perfectly. If somebody knows disadvantages of this solution, please comment this answer or add another, better. I had to modify @mmmshuddup's idea ([you can read the conversation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19391/discussion-between-mmmshuddup-and-katan87)).

First of all, the implementation of `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` in custom route class is no more necessary.

In `Module.php` within `onBootstrap` function:

```
    $app = $e->getApplication();
    $sm  = $app->getServiceManager();
    $sm->get('translator');
    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    $sm->setFactory('Navigation', 
                    'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory', true);

    $nav = $sm->get('Navigation');
    $alias = $sm->get('Application\Router\Alias');
    $alias->setNavigation($nav);
```

First we instantiate `Navigation` factory in `ServiceManager` and then our custom route. After that we can pass Navigation class into custom route using `setNavigation` function.
To complete instantiate of our custom route we need in `getServiceConfig` in the same file:

```
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Application\Router\Alias' => function($sm) {
                $alias = new \Application\Router\Alias('/node[/:id]');
                return $alias;
            },
            'db_adapter' =>  function($sm) {
                $config = $sm->get('Configuration');
                $dbAdapter = new \Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($config['db']);
                return $dbAdapter;
            },
        )
    );
```

And here is a tricky part. This instance is temporary. While routing, this class will be instantiated one more time and this is why, I think, it's not very elegant. We have to insert parameter into constructor however at this moment value of this parameter is not important.

The custom route class:

```
// file within ModuleName/src/ModuleName/Router/Alias.php
namespace Application\Router;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http;

class Alias extends Http\Segment
{

    private static $_navigation = null;

    public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
    {
        //some logic here

        //get Navigation
        $nav = self::$_navigation;

        return parent::match($request, $pathOffset);
    }

    public function setNavigation($navigation){
        self::$_navigation = $navigation;
    }

}
```

Because first instance is temporary, we have to collect our `Navigation` class in static variable. It's awful but works nice. Maybe there is a way to instantiate it only once and in route configuration get instance of it, but at this moment this is best answer for my question. Simply enough and working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>That is because the object itself really doesn't have [any properties declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4776208/486233).  But if you do this:</strike>

```
echo get_class($sl);
```

You will see that it is indeed an instance of `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`

You should be able to get your navigation instance by doing something like:

```
$nav = $sl->get('Navigation');
```

EDIT:

I just notice you have some stuff in the wrong location of your code.  You're calling `getServiceLocator()` *on* `$serviceLocator` which is already the instance of that.  Also you're calling it within **`setServiceLocator()`**.  You should change it to:

```
// EDIT - file within ModuleName/src/Router/Alias.php
namespace Application\Router;

use Traversable;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils;
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Mvc\Router\Http;

class Alias extends Http\Segment implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function match(Request $request, $pathOffset = null)
    {
        $nav = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Navigation');
        // ...
        return parent::match($request, $pathOffset);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Katan87 Sorry I had to leave right after answering so I didn't have a chance to take a close enough look until now.  Check out my edit.  That should help!

Comment: Hey, it's still not working. I've got error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object in [...] AliasSegment.php

Comment: @Katan87 Do you have the `implements` in there?  You should move this to a `Service` or `Router` namespace.

Comment: I've change `$this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;` into `$this->_serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;` and now I have an error: `Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Navigation'`

Comment: Ok then you need to check how you have `Navigation` setup.  Try taking it out of your **module.config.php** and put it into a `getServiceConfig()` function within **Module.php**.

Comment: Ok, Ive change whole file. It looks almost the same as You wrote however I had to add `use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;` and save it in `ModuleName/src/ModuleName/Router/Alias.php`. I inserted `'Navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
` into my `getServiceConfig()` and still the same error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19391/discussion-between-mmmshuddup-and-katan87)